# Can't use Pymouse

Tags: python

I have already installed `pymouse`, `pyuserinput`
[screen shot of cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWoJX.jpg)

But still when I am trying to import it on my python3.6 IDLE  I am getting this message:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Tony Stark\Desktop\pymouse.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyMouse import PyMouse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyMouse'
```

Comment: do you have VE ?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

`pip install --user PyMouse`.

It helped for same kind of error on my `Linux` machine.

Comment: mine is windows 10